# How to unlink files which has www-data ownership? [Laravel]

Tags: laravel, file, permissions, unlink, ownership

I've files in /public/images/ directory. It isn't allowing me to unlink files from the directory.

Comment: are you checking in localhost or live server?

Comment: any error or warning that it gives? post it with your question

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi locahost nginx, ubuntu

Comment: @HaiderAli No warnings. The data row is deleted. But the file isn't deleted.

Comment: execute this command in your terminal:-  sudo chmod 777 -Rf path/to/public_folder

Comment: let me know if it works so I can post it as answer

Comment: post your code for unlink file are you providing correct path

Comment: @HaiderAli `/** remove files*/
          if(file_exists($data->location)) {
              unlink(asset($data->location));
          }`

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi it works when I change owner permission to $USER. But the problem is the image is uploaded through server. So new images have www-data:www-data permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try** this:

```
if(file_exists($data->location)) { 
  unlink($data->location); 
  // this path should be public_path() not the url site path
}
```

**`Note`**:- **unlink** function allow the public or storage path not allowing the site or url path for unlinking.

**For example**:

**Allow** this path:

C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public

**Not allow** this path:

http://localhost/laravel/public

Comment: Sorry but this isn't working.. I think there is the problem with permission.

Comment: what is the output of **$data->location** ??

Comment: `/var/www/html/broadway/broadway-website/public/uploads/media_files/a.jpg
`

Comment: try to unlink image with putting the hard code path.

Comment: I don't know why it's now working even putting the hard code path with real file name. What might be the reason?

Comment: The reason I already mentioned in the answer is that : `unlink` should not be able to allow the dynamic path or url path. It's just allow the static path and you should set only the `image name` dynamic and rest of the path should be static.